# Asyck task to fetch image from sqlite

Tags: android

I am fetching image name from sqlite in doInBackground method of async task.and i started progress dialogue in pre Execution and dismiss the dialogue in post execution method.But problem is that loader is not moving properly.

Comment: Give some code. then someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> >   {
  private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Catalogue.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       progressDialog.setMessage("Loading, Please Wait .....");
       progressDialog.show();}
```